# Why Textview is not updating data everytime?

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to get text from `db` then update text in my `textView` of `recyclerView adapter` class . Although I'm getting `text` from db without any problem but my `textview` is not updating text everytime . Sometimes it's updating and sometimes it's not I wonder what's the problem . I tried to refer a lot of `SO` questions but none of them could solve my issue . I even tried to use `textView.invalidate()` but it was of no use . Could anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Code:

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder( CustomRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
JSONObject ov=new JSONObject();

            try {
                ov.put("prof_email",timelineData.getEmail());
                socket.disconnect();
                socket.connect();
                socket.emit("data",ov);

                socket.on("name_full", new Emitter.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {
                        final JSONObject ob = (JSONObject)args[0];
                        try {

                            final String st = ob.getString("fullname");


                            Needle.onMainThread().execute(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if (st.length() > 0) {
                                        //I'm toasting just to test that text is alright or not but it's alright
                                        Toast.makeText(context,st,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        holder.userName.invalidate();//here not useful
                                        holder.userName.setText(st);
                                        holder.userName.invalidate();//even here also not useful
                                        socket.disconnect();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to update the data list (which one usually passes to a RecyclerView.Adapter) and then call Adapter#notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: thanks for your answer @0X0nosugar but I'm not getting what are you saying

Comment: Can you check if you can update the textview using an actual activity or handler instead of needle instance, if you manage to update it, the problem would be with the initilization of needle object, just noticed you are using recycle view - use adapter.notifydatachange instead it should update the whole list

Comment: @AntonMakov great answer sir actually I didn't find any fault in **Needle** but your solution *adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()* worked like a charm

Comment: @AntonMakov now I'm having another problem this process is  not stopping it's repeating continuously . I don't know why it's happening

Comment: How do you create your adapter? I hope you are not connecting to socket each time you scroll the recycle view. If you are doing it you need to fetch the items by batches just search lazy loading in Android

Comment: If you still have issues place your whole code with the initilization of the adapter and I will try to help you out

Comment: @AntonMakov sir as you're right I'm connecting to socket every time.So, what can I do now to avoid this issue

Comment: @AntonMakov actually I'm prefectching data for recyclerview so do I need to use LazyLoader further

Comment: @AntonMakov sir could you please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49666365/8027365)

Answer (score 0):

OnBindViewHolder will be called every time when user scroll the recyclerview.
So corresponding to your source code, socket connection and disconnection is done many times when user scroll the list. (This seems not a good way)
So I recommend to remove socket related code from onBindViewHolder. 
After that just listening to the socket. When data changed, replace old data with new one from your collection and call Adapter#notifyDatasetChanged().

Comment: Sir thanks a lot for your time and great answer . Actually I realize that this socket connect and disconnect is totally inefficient .But as I've to get usernames according to position that's why I'm doing this . So, could you please suggest me how to avoid that socket connect disconnect

Comment: you can create an object that contains both the user name and the item(that you are showing in the recycleview) fetch them both before you set your adapter, when you all the data including the username you just present it as is