# How to load data to recyclerveiw adapter position wise?

Tags: android, socket.io, android-recyclerview

Actually I'm trying to show posts in recyclerview by getting a set of posts from server *(mongodb)* and it's working fine. Then I'm trying to load `post's username` by the help of `post_ owner_mail` .You might say why do I load these things position wise instead of bulk wise but as there will be posts with different `ownerMail` so it's not possible to prefetch their username. For that purpose I'm using a separate class for loading data from server and showing in text view . But now the problem is the although `textview` is setting username  but not all time and the recyclerview is **lagging** as well . Can anyone please help me to get rid of this problem.

Adapter Class Code :

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder( CustomRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
  //It's a data model class of image_links and post_owner_mails
  TimelineData timelineData=totalList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

 //It's the custom loader class through which I'm loading data and setting to txt view position wise
  LoadData d=new LoadData(hold.userNameTxtView,timelineData.getPostOwnerMail());

}
```

LoadData Class :

```
public class LoadData{
private Socket socket;
{
    try{
        socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.43.218:8080");
    }catch(URISyntaxException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
public LoadData(final TextView tv,final String email){
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.connect();
    JSONObject ob=new JSONObject();
    try {
        ob.put("getFullnameMail",email);
        socket.emit("data",ob);
        socket.on("fullname", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                final JSONObject ob=(JSONObject)args[0];
                Needle.onMainThread().execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            tv.setText(ob.getString("fullname"));
                            socket.disconnect();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }    
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Database Storing Pattern**:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa9304391b4ee28f4e4525d"),
"post_owner_mail" : "john.cena",
"time" : "14 Mar 2018(01-30-50)",
"img_link" : [ 
    "192.168.43.218:8080/user_info/john.cena/uploads/14 Mar 2018(01-30-50)/pic0.jpg", 
    "192.168.43.218:8080/user_info/john.cena/uploads/14 Mar 2018(01-30-50)/pic1.jpg"
],
"caption" : "#fun#cartoon"
}
```

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library

Comment: @pskink sir I'm a beginner so could you please elaborate how can I use 
 **paging library**  in my case

Comment: see `PagedListAdapter` class - you should use it as a base class of your adapter

Answer (score 0):

You have a few solutions to solve this issue:

1) you can combine the email address with the item that you are presenting to the user (basically you are creating a new object that contain the old data + the email, or just add another field to the old object), you require to have access to the database/server/service and just add the required field (email) that you are looking to add to each item.

2) if you don't have access to the database/service you can create a loader that will be presented to the user while you are loading those two items(old item and the email, you will have email fetched already for each item before you set your adapter)

3) a different approach would be to show the email upon request, just add a button(or image like arrow) and when the user clicks on it, it will request the email as you wished and present it in the item that you picked.

There are different approaches for your problem. 
If it's not important to show the email I would go with method 3.

Comment: Sir thanks again for your answer but could you please check my edited question . Actually I'm storing user uploaded posts in this format when the user will scroll to this position I'm getting his **fullname** and showing to them . Thus in my case what should I do

Comment: By the way let's assume even a situation that I'll store the **username** along with other data in the post saving format but I'll have to access the number of likes or comments on pictures by position wise approach . So, how to deal with this situation

Comment: You can simply your layout (by showing less information) when the user clicks on the item he can see the content/more details about it(another fragment/activity or even a dialog). Or you can do a loader button which will load every time one item.

Comment: Nice suggestion but do you think it would be user friendly for a social media app . Let's assume you're checking someone's post in social media platform but it would show the name only when you'll click the loader button .

Comment: I'm not using so much social media to be honest. I can tell you when you use email client application such as Gmail you usually see important things like subject, from where the email came from , if it has an attachment. You can see one sentence of the actual email but in order to see the whole email(post in your case) you need to click on it and see it in more detail. You need to show simple user interface rather than complex and not user friendly interface.

Comment: Makove okay fine I do respect your point of view. Now I'm noticing a unique pattern this username showing problem is happening only when number of items is "1"  this problem is not happening if *no of items are greater than one* so how to fix this?

Comment: I need to see your whole adapter implementation with setting the adapter to  your recycleview in order to help you out